# Calling clear on a JPA entity property using AccessType.PROPERTY fails

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I work with a map in an entity.

In the setter, I clear the map and then put all my values. I test the class, the values are there. I persist the entity: the values are not persisted and the `save` method of the repository return me an entity without the values!!!
I try without the `clear` ... it's working!

After some experimentation, I find something: I try with a basic entity and the same mapping. When the access type is PROPERTY, it doesn't work, but when I try with access type FIELD, it work.

So the problem seems to be the behavior around the acces type. And unfortunatly, I can't change my class hyerarchy (for some working reasons)

Here is the property and getter:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyEntity {

    private Map<MyEnum, Integer> myEnums = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

    // (...)

    @Override
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "my_enum", columnDefinition = "enum('A', 'B', 'C')")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Map<MyEnum, Integer> getMyEnums() {
        return myEnums;
    }

    void setMyEnums(Map<MyEnum, Integer> myEnums) {

        // this work
        // this.myEnums= new EnumMap<>(myEnums);

        // this work to (but I can't keep it because the map is not cleared)
        // for (MyEnum myEnum : myEnums.keySet()) this.myEnums.put(myEnum, myEnums.get(myEnum));

        // this doesn't work
        this.myEnums.clear();
        for (MyEnum myEnum : myEnums.keySet()) this.myEnums.put(myEnum, myEnums.get(myEnum));
    }

    // (...)

}
```

I really think there is an issue here.

Is there a way to work with AccessType.PROPERTY and avoid this behavior? I need to use the `clear()` method and the access type PROPERTY.

For information, it's a `spring-boot` project and I reproduce the problem with 1.5.3.RELEASE and 2.0.3.RELEASE.

I create a unit test to reproduce this issue:
https://github.com/Mohicane/jpa-accesstype

Comment: Why do you need AccessType.Property and where are the rest of your annotations? On the field or on the  property?

Comment: I work with an historical library from my company. I have to make some class become entity and one of them have maps declared final.
I choose to override this class and I thought that AccesTypeProperty will be a simple way to handle this problem...

I post this example that reproduce the unwanted behavior. As you could see, there is only one annotation for the access type.

Answer (score 1):

> In the setter, I clear the map and then put all my values.

That's a bad idea. Don't do that. If you want to merge a collection, [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/) explains how to do that.

> Is there a way to work with AccessType.PROPERTY and avoid this behavior?

Yes, of course, there is a way. Just don't `clear` the persistent collection since the `DELETE` phase is executed after the INSERT `phase` during the Persistence Context flush according to the Hibernate [`ActionQueue`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/) rules.

> I need to use the clear() method and the access type PROPERTY.

No, you don't need to use `clear`. You need to do a proper collection [`merge`](https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. But I say something wrong: I don't have to use `clear()`. The original class (the one I herited) use it ... Maybe delegating pattern is the only solution. But I will read your documentation before.

Comment: I read the doc, so ok I understand operations order. But why such a difference between `AccessType.FIELD` and `AccessType.PROPERTY`? Moreover, it's not about entities collection but basics collection.

Comment: You can debug it and see why the behavior differs, but it makes no difference since you should not do that anyway.

Comment: I'm not a JPA specialist so if you could give a hint about the classes I must watch for debugging. I see this behavior only through my entity state.

Comment: Try debugging  the DefaultFlushEventListener and see where the two options differ.

Comment: After the call to clear (in AccessType.PROPERTY mode) during persist method, the argument map become empty. I verify the code several time, event just before to post this comment in order to be sure I don't call clear on the argument ... but not! What is this?!?!

Comment: Open a Jira issue if you think you found an issue. Don't forget to add a replicating test case as well. Also, if this is important to you, you should provide a Pull Request with a fix too.